# Code design in application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF in C# and I would like the user to be able to design code visually by using a point and click system.

I have considered using a TreeView to visualize the code or some kind of a graph/flow chart.

Could anyone suggest a good solution or control for this?

Thanks

Comment: Good luck. This won't be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree view won't cut it. Depends on what language you want to use. Take a loot at [blockly](https://code.google.com/p/blockly/). You will have to implement something similar. Some sort of canvas and blocks that only can connect in certain way.

Comment: It will most likely be building for C#. But thank you, I'd thought of graphs/flow charts but that seems to be a good solution.